# Code Igniter No DB connection in database config file

Tags: php, mysql, macos, codeigniter, localhost

I just clone my code igniter project in mac. When i run it show like this.
[image]

I've already add database.php in folder config like this.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'zyacbt',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE,
);
```

My xampp mysql run in port 3307. It's work fine when i try in windows.
How to fix this ?

Comment: if you're deploying on linux or mac server mysql runs on 3306 port not 3307 not sure for xampp on mac also make sure that mysql is working on your environment and it has database specified in config

Comment: i've try change port to 3306 but still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using localhost:3306 or 127.0.0.1:3306?

Also worth running a dummy mysql connection through php code (outside CI) to make sure if the connection works at all, or the if the problem is within CI.